# Can't build/run iOS app using Xcode however 'cordova run ios' works fine

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I used to build and run it for test on iPhone 4s on the same setup I have now and it was working fine, now I'm trying to run it for test on iPhone 5S, but it doesn't work.

There is a known problem with Phonegap GAplugin and the arm64, which I used to remove the arm64 from valid architectures in target.

First time I tried, I got the following error:

```
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=arm64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s).
```

I changed "Build Active Architectures ONLY" on targets to "No", then I got the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_CDVPageDidLoadNotification", referenced from:
      -[CDVSplashScreen pluginInitialize] in CDVSplashScreen.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVWebViewDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVInAppBrowser.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GAPlugin in GAPlugin.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_IonicKeyboard in IonicKeyboard.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVBarcodeScanner in CDVBarcodeScanner.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DFPPlugin in DFPPlugin.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PushNotification in PushNotification.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SocialSharing in SocialSharing.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVDevice in CDVDevice.o
      ...
  "_CDVLocalNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVDevice.o
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_CDVViewController_$_StatusBar in CDVStatusBar.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVUserAgentUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVInAppBrowser.o
  "_CDVRemoteNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GAPlugin in GAPlugin.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_IonicKeyboard in IonicKeyboard.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVBarcodeScanner in CDVBarcodeScanner.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_DFPPlugin in DFPPlugin.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PushNotification in PushNotification.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SocialSharing in SocialSharing.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVDevice in CDVDevice.o
      ...
  "_CDVRemoteNotificationError", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[CDVInAppBrowser openInSystem:] in CDVInAppBrowser.o
      -[FacebookConnectPlugin initWithWebView:] in FacebookConnectPlugin.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPluginResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GAPlugin.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVBarcodeScanner.o
      objc-class-ref in DFPPlugin.o
      objc-class-ref in PushNotification.o
      objc-class-ref in SocialSharing.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVDevice.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVNotification.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The strange thing that I still can test the app on the new setup using "cordova run ios" but I can't build it for release! What should I do?

Cordova version: 4.1.2

Xcode Version: 6.1

Test device: iPhone 5S with iOS 8

Cordova plugins

- com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin 2.3.1 "GAPlugin"
- com.google.playservices 18.0.0 "Google Play Services for Android"
- com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.3 "Keyboard"
- com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner 2.0.0 "BarcodeScanner"
- com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect 0.10.0 "Facebook Connect"
- com.postmedia.DFPPlugin 0.0.4 "DFPPlugin"
- com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh 3.3.0 "Pushwoosh"
- nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing 4.3.8 "SocialSharing"
- org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.12 "Device"
- org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.2.10 "Notification"
- org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.10 "Geolocation"
- org.apache.cordova.globalization 0.2.8 "Globalization"
- org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.5.3 "InAppBrowser"
- org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.10 "Network Information"
- org.apache.cordova.splashscreen 0.3.3 "Splashscreen"
- org.apache.cordova.statusbar 0.1.8 "StatusBar"
- org.pushandplay.cordova.apprate 1.1 "AppRate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the iPhone 4s emulator, and everything worked fine. Then I disconnected my iPhone 5s and archived the app.

So, I think there is no way to run ARMV7 architecture only on iPhone 5S in development through Xcode, but you can do that through "cordova run ios"

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue… probably a outdated Xcode project. I simply ran these commands:

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Then, open the new Xcode project and run.It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are writing code in myapp/www/index.html (that is the path for cordova run android or cordova run ios etc).

If you want to build through XCode or Eclipse (Android) you should write your code in myapp/platforms/ios/www/index.html

OBVIOUSLY copy all the necessary files (js and css and images, all!) to run your app and then create a project in XCode

Those are the 2 approaches of Phonegap (Cli based and multiplatform or Platform specific)

Hope it helps!